# Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema con este código php, ayer me funcionaba y me insertaba en la base de datos, hoy he añadido un campo nuevo a la base de datos y ya no me ha funcionado
Código HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <label for="nombreBoletin" class="control-label">Nombre Boletín</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombreBoletin" id="nombreBoletin"><br>
        <label for="archivoPDF" class="control-label">Archivo PDF</label>
        <input type="file" name="archivoPDF" id="archivoPDF"><br>
        <label for="provincia" class="control-label">Provincia</label>
        <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia"><br>
        <label for="fechaBoletin" class="control-label">Fecha Boletín</label>
        <input type="text" name="fechaBoletin" id="fechaBoletin" value="aaaa/mm/dd"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" id="enviar">
    </form>
```

Código PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO boletines(nombre, pdf, provincia_comunidad_autonoma, fecha_boletin, nombre_boletin) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)");
    $blob = null;
    $fileName = $_FILES['archivoPDF']['name'];
    $fecha = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['fechaBoletin']));
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
    $nombreBoletin = $_POST['nombreBoletin']; /*Añadido hoy*/
    $stmt->bind_param( 'sbss', $fileName, $blob, $provincia, $fecha, $nombreBoletin);
    $stmt->send_long_data( 1, file_get_contents($_FILES['archivoPDF']['tmp_name']));
    $path = "uploads/".$_FILES['archivoPDF']['name'];
    if ( $consulta = $stmt->execute()){
      echo '';
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivoPDF']['tmp_name'],$path);
    }else{
      echo 'Error en la insercion de datos';
    }
     
}
```

Cuando envío el formulario me sale el siguiente error: `mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`

Gracias.

Comment: Una cosa, aparte de añadir un campo en la base de datos, ¿no has cambiado el código? El error te está diciendo que en la cadena 'sbss' solo hay cuatro caracteres cuando se requieren cinco, el número de argumentos que pasas a continuación y que se corresponde con el número de marcadores ? que hay en tu consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje de error es bastante claro:

> Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables mysqli

Mi traducción libre:

> El número de elementos en el string de definición de tipos no coincide con el número de variables vinculadas mysqli

Y es que tu sentencia `insert` tiene 5 campos, y en la llamada a `bind_param()`, si bien pasas las 5 variables, el primer parámetro, que es la cadena de definición de tipos, tienes solamente 4 caracteres:

```
$stmt->bind_param( 'sbss', $fileName, $blob, $provincia, $fecha, $nombreBoletin);
```

Suponiendo que la última variable es una cadena, debieras pasar `'sbsss'`: una `s` más al final indica que el último parámetro es de tipo string. Al final, quedaría así:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sbsss', $fileName, $blob, $provincia, $fecha, $nombreBoletin);
```

Más información en la [documentación de *bind_param()*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), que ya advierte:

> **El número de variables y la longitud de la cadena types debe coincidir con los parámetros en la sentencia**.